# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using @import in CSS

Tags: html, css

Learning something new about CSS every day and I've come across @import. What the advantages and disadvantages of using it.

I know that you can link all your stylesheets in one stylesheet using @import. Then have that one stylesheet linked to all your HTML documents and not have multiple CSS urls on every HTML document. But what are the advantages or disadvantages using this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, loading your CSS files using the `@import` method could significantly increase page load times as the individual files are then referenced one after the other. File B won't load till File A has downloaded. CSS referenced using the `<link>` tag on the other hand, can be downloaded simultaneously.

While this does seem like an outright disadvantage, using the `@import` method does lend a pretty outstanding advantage; Organisation.

As your project grows in size and complexity, maintaining your CSS files, however organised and picky you are, can become a chore, to say the least. The `@import` method helps you break your massive stylesheet into more comprehensible and logical portions.

To illustrate, you would typically reference your CSS file through a single `<link>` tag like so:

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This stylesheet could then reference several other subsidiary stylesheets,

```
@import url('/styles/navbar.css')
@import url('/styles/header.css')
@import url('/styles/typography.css')
@import url('/styles/grid.css')
```

This is just a rudimentary example off the top of my head, but hopefully you can see the potential of much more organised system. This can also make it easier for other team members to better understand where the referenced styles have been declared.

> Blockquote **Note** Just make sure these imports are at the very top of the stylesheet. There shouldn't be any declarations/content before this. This also includes `<-- comments -->`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to include a stylesheet in your web page. You can use the LINK tag:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='a.css'>
```

Or you can use the @import rule:

```
<style>
@import url("/styles/default.css");
</style>
```

I prefer using LINK for simplicity—you have to remember to put @import at the top of the style block or else it won’t work. It turns out that avoiding @import is better for performance, too.

**THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN @IMPORT AND LINK**

Before deciding which method to use to include your style sheets, you should understand what the two methods were intended to be used for.

**Link** - 
Linking is the first method for including an external style sheet on your Web pages. It is intended to link together your Web page with your style sheet. It is added to the  of your HTML document like this:

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**WHY USE LINK?**

The number one reason for using linked style sheets is to provide alternate style sheets for your customers. Browsers like Firefox, Safari, and Opera support the rel="alternate stylesheet" attribute and when there is one available will allow viewers to switch between them. You can also use a JavaScript switcher to switch between style sheets in IE. This is most often used with Zoom Layouts for accessibility purposes.

One of the drawbacks to using @import is that if you have a very simple  with just the @import rule in it, your pages may display a "flash of unstyled content" (FOUC) as they are loading. This can be jarring to your viewers.

A simple fix to this is to make sure you have at least one additional  or  element in your .

**@import** - 
Importing allows you to import one style sheet into another. This is slightly different than the link scenario, because you can import style sheets inside a linked style sheet. If you include an @import in the head of your HTML document, it is written like this:

```
<style type="text/css">@import url("styles.css");</style>
```

**WHY USE @IMPORT?**

Many years ago, the most common reason that was given for using @import instead (or along with)  is because older browsers didn't recognize @import, so you could hide styles from them.

By importing your style sheets, you would essentially be making them available to more modern, standards compliant browsers while "hiding" them from the older browser versions.

Another use for the @import method is to use multiple style sheets on a page, while only including a single link in your document's .

From a standards viewpoint, there is no difference between linking to an external style sheet or importing it. Either way is correct and either way will work equally well (in most cases). However, there are a few reasons you might want to use one over the other.